# How to suppress some rule for C# .Net?

Tags: c#, sonarqube

How can I suppress rule id: S1118 "Utility classes should not have public constructors." using Sonarqube 4.5 with MsBuild 4.0

I've tried `SuppressMessageAttribute`, but it wasn't successful.

Comment: Which products are you using? SonarLint for Visual Studio? Scanner for MsBuild? Which version of MsBuild are you using to build your solution?

Comment: We are using Scanner for MsBuild 4.0. Could you provide some examples of using SuppressMessageAttribute for your product?

Comment: The SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild works best with MSBuild version 14. MSBuild 12 and MSBuild 4 is not supported.